# Compiler error with if-conditions

Tags: c++

Do if statements work this way? This is a "guess the number" game. The 1st if says to go higher/lower, the 2nd if says if you're within a 50, 100 or 100+ range.

Both are supposed to work simultaneously, but I get an error.

> Line 37 unexpected primary expression before '| |' token, Line 38
>   expected ';' before 'cout'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Please enter a number\n";

    srand(time(0));
    int y = rand();

    while (x != y)
    {
        cin >> x;
        {

        if (!(cin.good()))            //1st if
        {
           cout << "No letters noob" << endl;
           cin.clear();
           cin.sync();
        }
        else if (x < y)
           cout << "Go higher" << endl;
        else if (x > y)
           cout << "Go lower" << endl;
        else
           cout << "You win!!" << endl;
        }

        {

        if (y - x - 50 <= 0) || (x - y - 50 <= 0)        //2nd if
           cout << "within 50 range" << endl;
        else if (y - x - 100 <= 0) || (x - y - 100 <= 0)
           cout << "within 100 range" << endl;
        else
           cout << "100+ value away" << endl;
        }
    }
cin.get();
getchar();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Also am I making the code too complicated or is this readable?

Comment: You have extra braces whose point is unclear, and some key missing parentheses.

Comment: Line 37  unexpected primary expression before '| |' token      Line 38 expected ';' before 'cout'      Line 39 unexpected primary expression before '| |' token          Line 40 expected ';' before 'cout'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing parentheses.

For example, this line:

```
if (y - x - 50 <= 0) || (x - y - 50 <= 0)
```

Should read:

```
if ((y - x - 50 <= 0) || (x - y - 50 <= 0))
```

Because the entire if condition must be wrapped in parentheses.

Looks like you may have some other issues there as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct answer by @jonathan-wood, the following may express your intent more clearly:

```
#include <cstdlib>
...
const int off_by = abs(x - y);

if (off_by <= 50) {
    ...
} else if (off_by <= 100) {
    ...
}
```

FYI: if you think it would improve your code's readability, you can also use "or" and "and" instead of "||" and "&&". So, the following is legal:

```
if ((y - x - 50 <= 0) or (x - y - 50 <= 0)) {
    ...
}
```